# Recommended nginx setup for AngularJS as front end and Symfony2 as back end

Tags: angularjs, symfony, nginx

I want to use **Symfony2** as back end to create a **REST API** and use **AngularJS** as **front end**. The 2 are completely separated ie Symfony 2 will not render anything, it'll just send json data to AngularJS.

**I'm not sure on how to configure my web server (nginx).**

[The Symfony documentation gives the configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html#nginx) but it's intended for a site that only uses Symfony, and so everything outside of the `/web/` folder is not accessible.

I can see several possibilities:

1. Create 2 different directories (eg `/path/frontend` and `/path/backend`) and a corresponding website for both. I would then have 2 different addresses to access the front end and the back end (eg `http://myfrontend.com` and `http://mybackend.com`). The problem I see is that I probably won't be able to directly use AJAX calls in AngularJS.
2. Create 2 different directories (eg `/website/frontend` and `/website/backend`) and only one website. I would then probably need to access the front end and back end with something like `http://example.com/frontend` and `http://example.com/backend`. I'm not sure how to configure the web server though (issue with `root /website/backend/web`).
3. Put the AngularJS directory inside the `web` folder of Symfony, but then I'd need to also change the configuration so that nginx doesn't only server app.php, app_dev.php and config.php.
4. Put the AngularJS directory in the `src` folder of Symfony, and have Symfony handle the routing. I don't know if it will mess with AngularJS' one routing. Also I will probably have a few other php that should be accessible, so I'd need to route them through Symfony also.

**What would you suggest and why?** Maybe I'm missing something obivous?

Comment: Are you going for a single page app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you could accomplish your task using any of those methods. It would come down to how you want to structure you application and what it's objectives are. For large scale projects the first method (having the API separate from the AngularJS) would serve you well. Twitter really made that software model big.

So I would suggest going with method one. All you would have to do is specify an Nginx header in your server block that allows cross domain access to another domain. So you would specify the following directive in your frontendangular.com site:

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin backendsymfony.com;
```

This way every time a page request comes in on your front end app Nginx tells the browser that it is safe to access another domain (your symfony setup).

Comment: It indeed looks like the easiest thing to do, also I like the fact that the front end is separated from the back end.

Answer (score 0):

These are 2 frameworks that both have powerful routing capabilities, and it looks like you are going for a best of both worlds.  There are many pros and cons to any setup, so I'll list a few that come to mind:

- **Angular routing / templating is great but** it will leave you with **SEO and meta issues to solve** . It's probably better to manage your major pages with symfony2 and any routing within each page with angular. This would allow you to still make dynamic pages w/out compromising your meta and SEO control. Access Control seems flexible but probably not necessary, I would just put all calls to REST API under `http://www.thesite.com/api` and if I need another setup something like `https://api.thesite.com`,  nginx can route or proxypass this without leaving the domain.
- Locating partials gets a little wonky but that's probably fine for a large application. Just note that you will probably need to search the js location object for `[host] / [path] /web/bundles/someBundle/public/blah...`.  Or you can setup a '/partials' path in nginx.
- **Twig and Angular tpl** may end up a confusing mix as **they both use {{foo}}.** This alone would make me reconsider mixing the 2, and I might look to go with a frontend server, like node with `ejs` where I could also benefit from the streaming transfer of the data sent from the API.

You can get around it easy enough with but it's still concerning:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).config(function($interpolateProvider){
           $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[').endSymbol(']]');
       }
 );
```

- You do get the benefit of angular partials as symfony twig, which can be good or bad depending on how you see the flexibility being used. I have seen guys making examples of forms that fill out values with symfony data, but they are just undermining the power of angulars binding.

Don't get me wrong, I actually do really like the idea of the two harmonizing.

Just food for thought - cheers

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. I realize now that most of the site will be private and require to log in, so there won't be SEO issues for that. Maybe the small part that would be public wouldn't use AngularJS.